# Adding content into existing ordered list with PHP and/or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Working with a storefront (WooCommerce/WordPress) that sells CDs, and each album/product page has a track listing in an ordered list that already exists in a standard WordPress editor field. Now I need to be able to add audio samples for each of those tracks inside the tracklisting. But rather than manually adding each audio track/player, I'm looking for help to create a function within the product template that will add an audio sample track before (or within) each of the "li" elements. Below is as far as I've gotten in order to get the player into the list items in the correct way, but the issue is how to get the Track Number to increase within the list.

```
function samples_audio(){
    $cloudbase = 'http://domain.com';
    $directory = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'directory', true);
    $trackprep = 'track';
    $num = 0;
    $sep = '/';
    $source = $cloudbase.$sep.$catno.$sep.$trackprep.$num;
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var AudioPlayer = "<?php echo $source; ?>";
            var TrackNo = 0 + 1;
            jQuery('.tracks li').before('<audio controls><source src="'+ AudioPlayer +''+ TrackNo +'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
        </script>
        <?php 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Each product is an audio track i suppose. So people can listen at some kind of short audio preview (audio sample) of this audio product (or not?). So you have already a track number for each audio product (or not?). So what you want exactly for `$tracknumber`: to have the same value as product track (in a different `$directory`) or another thing? Please can you clarify your question, updating it? you say you have already content in ordered list, could you give us more details? how you upload your content and where?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Each product is a full album, then on that album page is the tracklisting, which is already entered in a WordPress content editor in an ordered list in order to have the correct tracklisting. Now there have audio previews/samples of each of those tracks for each of the albums, and I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to add those samples into the tracklisting without manually doing it track-by-track.

Comment: Outside your loop, you define `$track = 0;`. Inside your loop; you increment the value of your variable *$track* this way `$track=+ 1;`. then use an *if else* like that `$track < 10 ? '0'.$track : ''.$track;` *(to get 01, 02, 03… to 99 instead of getting 1, 2, 3… to 99)*. Let me know if it works. I can't do it more than that, because i will need your detailed code. Try it and let us know…

Comment: Thanks for the help with the track numbering!

Comment: I think it will be once I figure out how to create the loop for each existing li element. Still not there quite yet. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: LoicTheAztec - Thanks for your help so far. I've updated the post with my latest code that has gotten me the closest.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using the each() and index functions of jquery with the php. I added the following to the content-single-product.php template in WooCommerce:

```
<?php
$cloudbase = 'http://domain.com';
$directory = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'directory', true);
$trackprep = 'track';
$sep = '/';
$source = $cloudbase.$sep.$catno.$sep.$trackprep.$num;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.tracks li').each(function(indexInt){
    var AudioPlayer = "<?php echo $source; ?>";
    if (indexInt <= 9) {
        jQuery(this).before('<audio><source src="'+ AudioPlayer +'0'+ (indexInt +1 )+'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
    }
    if (indexInt >= 10){
        jQuery(this).before('<audio><source src="'+ AudioPlayer +''+ (indexInt +1 )+'.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
    }
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps someone else in the future.